# Utilizando dois ResultSet + UserList

Tags: banco-de-dados, lista, resultset

Estou fazendo duas pesquisas distintas no banco de dados que irão retornar vários dados que serão inseridos em uma lista.

Preciso criar uma unica lista com esses dados.

E as pesquisas devem concatenar uma com a outra. A primeira posição da lista lista[0] vai salvar a primeira pesquisa no banco. Depois tenho que fazer outra pesquisa no banco que vai retornar para a mesma lista só que será incluído no final de cada posição da lista.

Por exemplo

a primeira pesquisa retornou codigo, nome, idade

vai ser inserido na lista (codigo, nome, idade) na posição 0

a segunda pesquisa retornou sobrenome, peso, altura

vai ser inserido na mesma lista (codigo, nome, idade, sobrenome, peso, altura)

A linguagem é java, está sendo feito uma operação para pegar os dados do banco para criação de contas no google. Não posso mostrar as tabelas porque são da empresa

Existe alguma forma de fazer isto?

Comment: Pode publicar o modelo das tabelas ? Essa operação vai ser feita direto banco ou esta usando alguma aplicação ? Se sim, qual linguagem ?